# Download LightSwitch template to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Hey I am using VS 2012 professional and I noticed I don't have LightSwitch project template at all so I cannot start a new LightSwitch project.

Can anyone tell me where I can download it from?

the full package LightSwitch and LightSwitch Html.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search bought [this link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2381b03b-5c71-4847-a58e-5cfa48d418dc) out at number 1.

Also, you could use [Visual Studio 2013 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) along with [Lightswitch for Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/11/12/develop-lightswitch-and-cloud-business-apps-using-visual-studio-community-2013.aspx) to take advantage of the latest Lightswitch tools and templates. The HTML templates and tools are far more established in VS2013 than in VS2012.

Comment: Paul, your first link is for the *LightSwitch Extensibility Toolkit*, which is for creating LightSwitch *extensions* such as Silverlight controls, business types, templates, themes etc, and is not required for normal LightSwitch development.

Comment: Well spotted Yann, hopefully he or she will take my advice about VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of finding a template when you're not sure where to look in the template tree, is to type the name into the *Quick Launch* box in the top right-hand corner of Visual Studio. Having said that, LightSwitch project templates are not generally hard to find, but I guess it helps if you've been using LightSwitch for a long time like I have.

Also, make sure that you didn't uncheck "LightSwitch" in the install options when you installed Visual Studio. You can always do a "repair" of Visual Studio to check, then just check the box if you did, and let the repair/change process complete.

If you do follow the suggestion that was made to use Visual Studio 2013 (and I would highly recommend doing so), be aware that it will want to "upgrade" your project, which will mean that you won't be able to open it in VS 2012 anymore. **It's a one-way change** (unfortunately)! Keep a verified backup of your 2012 project if you do decide to go this way. The upgrade process will make one for you, but I'd advise you to make one of your own first as well (belts and braces etc).

I'd also advise to go through the upgrade process with a **copy** of your project first, and have a play around with it in VS 2013 before you decide to use it for that project. If you make significant changes in the upgraded project, then decide you want to go back to VS 2012, you'll have to duplicate any new work that you did in the 2013 project in the backup of the original project, there's no easy way to copy/paste most items (except for code of course).

Every new version of Visual Studio has included some sort of changes to the internals of LightSwitch projects, which has rendered them unable to be opened in earlier versions of VS. The same is currently true in VS 2015 CTP6 as well from my existing trials of it.